# Positioning div vertically

Tags: html, css, center, vertical-alignment

I got something like this:

[image]

**Solution right now:**
fixed height and negative top-value.

Now I want to position the red box vertically in the parent div, but it must be flexible, because there are options that might extend the red box with one or two more text-rows.

Sizes are 840x300px and the code right now is:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="large-16 columns item">
<div class="box">
  <div class="image"><img src="system/html/band_test1-f5641934.jpg"></div>
  <div class="data red">
    <h1><a href="www.google.de" title="headliner" target="_blank">SEHR LANGER BANDNAME AHOI</a></h1>
    <h2><a href="" title="venue" target="_blank"></a></h2>
    <p class="date">So, 28.07.2013</p>
    <p class="supportbands">+ <a href="" title="Test Support" target="_blank">Test Support</a>  </p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.showsblock .item {
    height: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.box .image img {
    border: 1px solid #a2a2a2;
}
.box .data {
    background: url('../show_bg_black.png') repeat;
    display: inline-block;

    position: relative;
    top: -165px;
    left: 1px;

    padding-right: 10px;
    min-width: 290px;

}
```

This isn't very flexibel. When I add one more row into the red div, it expands but isn't centered anymore. Do you have an idea?
Also, I think there might be a better solution for the "image" div.

thank you.

Comment: Where's the css for the data red?

Comment: Red ist just a red background png. Nothing important. Sry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using CSS tables (e.g `display:table-cell`) and `vertical-align:middle`.

**[See this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tUQ4z/1/)**

---

**EDIT**

---

Place the image in `absolute` position and the text container in `relative` position. Same principle for vertical alignment with CSS tables.

**[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tUQ4z/5/)**

Comment: Good Idea, but I cannot put the image into the CSS code. It will  be generated dynamically.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest `position: absolute`

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/kKWUH/2/

```
div.data {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin: auto;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    height:150px;
}
```

This will vertically align the div centrally. You can padding the top to bring it down a little etc.

Comment: Looking good but what happens when I add 1-2-3 rows of text? It seems that the "data"-box doesn't extend, does it?

Comment: I've added a height of 150px that's why. You could change this to another number or auto etc

Comment: When I changed it to auto, it goes the full height of the parent div. I just need it to the last row of the data-div. Do you have an idea?